# add_menu_page does not render the expected result

Tags: menus, pages, admin

I'm trying to accomplish the simple task of adding a new page to the admin area but it seems that I just cannot wrap my mind around this simple function.

Via codex, this is how I'm trying to add the page:

```
public function __construct(){
    add_action('admin_menu', array( &$this, 'register_menu_page'));
}

public function register_menu_page () {
    $hookname = add_menu_page (
            'My Slider',
            'My Slider',
            'manage_options',
            'my_slider',
            My_Slider::render_admin_menu()
        );
}
```

When pressing the newly added button named `My Slider` I would expect the `My_Slider::render_admin_menu()` to be called and populate the right side of the page with some HTML (while keeping the left menu intact).

However this is what I'm getting:

[image: text that always appears]

First of all, you can see that the rendering function is always called (I'm currently on the Dashboard page) and it is weirdly inserted on the top of the page.

Second of all, when the button is pressed, wordpress is trying to access `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/my_slider`.

What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: Use `array( $this, 'callback_to_method' )` instead. And please add the callback method to your question.

Comment: @kaiser Ok this is unbelievable for me. It works with the `array(&$this, 'callback_to_method' )`. Well this was a fun, well spent afternoon:) Thank you!

Comment: Please don't use `&$this`. Since PHP 5 (and WP needs a min. of 5.2.7), _every_ object is passed as reference. So just use `$this`. And about your problem: You should read about `static`, as this is what you tried to - calling a `static` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the 5 parameter to [add_menu_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) you send the resultat of running the function, insted of sending a [callable reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) to the function, as you did in the add_action.

```
$hookname = add_menu_page (
        'My Slider',
        'My Slider',
        'manage_options',
        'my_slider',
        array( 'My_Slider', 'render_admin_menu')
    );
```